# Kubernetes : container application process 'Local Address' change from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, containers, amazon-eks

I am redeploying an application on a fresh EKS cluster in kubernetes 1.28

My application is running on 3000 port

After Deploying the application it is running on containers Local Address 127.0.0.1:3000 instead of 0.0.0.0:3000, causing application not accessable through service internal endpoint (account-svc.default.svc.cluster.local)

Same application is running on different cluster (k8s 1.24) on 0.0.0.0:3000 and getting exposed.

Netstat output inside container in k8s 1.28
`Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name     tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24/node`

Tried executing in the server and checking bindings.

Deployed Same running image of application in old and new EKS clusters (1.24 and 1.28) Still in 1.24 Local address is 0.0.0.0:3000 and in 1.28 Local address is 127.0.0.1:3000